# Date.getTimezoneOffset returns a non integer value

Tags: javascript, timezone, dst

The following line in my code:

```
var timezoneoffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

returns -120.14933013916015.

I was expecting that the return value will be 120, and in general, that the value is always an integer.

Can anyone explain this? Right now it seems like I'll need to perform a round operation on the result.

Comment: Which browser is this?

Comment: Does this occur on all browsers, and is this repeatable everywhere?

Comment: IE10. it repeats on another machine here in the office. Also, it is happening with different timezones.

Comment: What time zone is your computer set to? And which version of Windows?

Comment: It happens when I set it to different timezones so it is not a specific timezone issue. The computer is running Win7-64

Comment: Got similar result. UA: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0. Got TZ offset -179.99999999956577 instead of -180.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried everything I can think of, and cannot reproduce the problem you are reporting.

The only thing I can think of is that something else in your code is modifying the `Date` prototype.  Perhaps you are using some date/time library that you didn't tell us about?

Please try reproducing the problem in a clean empty console.

- Type `about:blank` in the URL bar
- Press F12 for developer tools
- Go to the "Console" tab
- Type `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` into the console.

Does it still show the decimals?

- If yes, then there's a bug in IE or Windows
- If no, then something in your other code was mucking with the `Date` prototype.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've followed your guidlines and the answer is no - the output is an integer number. I'll try to find if something in the code that modifies the Date type.

Comment: Are you using any date libraries? Moment.js, date.js, XDate, or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Time-zone offset is the result of the difference from UTC and local time, this value represent minutes, AND if the value is negative, the offset is ahead of the UTC, having that in mind this simple line of code could give you the offset as traditional represented in hours.

```
var offset = (new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/-60);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var timezoneoffset        = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
var timezoneoffsetinteger = parseInt(timezoneoffset);
```

the variable time timezoneoffsetinteger will equal -120 as an integer. I guess you're in GMT+2?

If you wanted it to be a positive for GMT+ and negative for GMT- you'd then need to do:

```
var timezoneoffsetconvert = timezoneoffsetinteger * (-2) / 2
```

This would return (for GMT+2 (-120)) 120

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I know that I can do that (as I stated in the question). I'm trying to understand why I get an incorrect result in the first place.

Comment: getTimezoneOffset(); gets the current timezone then works out what it needs to do to get to UTC so for GMT+2 it would need to - 2 hours (120 mins)